# Please help with debug procedure

Tags: xcode

Could someone please guide me ..... I am a first timer.  I have an app that runs in Xcode and before I send it off to Apple I would like to (in an ideal world) debug it on both my 5s and my iPad.  I am sure that there is probably an easy procedure that I have to go through in order to put it on both devices but never having done it before I am a bit in the dark.  Would someone who has done this before please give me a hand.  Latest OS is on the phone and iPad and iTunes connect is on the MBP, not sure if that is key.  Many thanks

Comment: @bmike not quite sure as to why you put the question on hold, as you can see the question was answered 21 minutes before you put it on hold?

Comment: It needs to be clarified so we can decide if it belongs here or on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @bmike forgive me but you putting the question on hold seems a bit pointless. I asked the question, it took 3 people to view it before it was answered, I thanked the user that answered,and voted up his answer all before you put the question on hold and can I assume voted down my question?

Comment: @bmike, under [What topics can I ask about here?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the section where is says "...Please refrain from asking about the following topics..." while it does state "Code-level programming questions (cocoa, LLVM, etc…) are off-topic here." nonetheless it also states "We do encourage AppleScript, Automator, and UNIX shell scripting questions as well as how to use tools like Xcode for non-language specific tasks." and I certainly think the question asked falls within "how to use tools like Xcode" in the "We do encourage..." statement.

Comment: I'm glad you have your answer. The hold just prevents others from trying to guess what you meant. If you don't want to edit the post, no worries. If you decide you need more answers, just edit or flag it and either will have someone look at the hold to see if it should be lifted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at: [Launching Your App on Devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html)